# How to serve a terminal app (using fzf) cross-platforms in python

Tags: python, fzf

I've been building a [tool](https://github.com/jeanCarloMachado/PythonSearch) that heavily relies on [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) (a text application) as the UI. To make it work multi-platform I'm kind of supporting different terminal GUIs for each platform (Mac, Linux). I wonder if there's is a more elegant way to be multi-platform, for instance, to embed a terminal emulator inside a GUI toolkit (in Python). Is this possible? Any recommendations of approaches or tools?

Comment: Well, you could create your own terminal UI, use the ```sys``` module to check the platform, and run commands using the ```os``` module accordingly.

Comment: That is the current approach :).

Comment: Oh so you want to get the actual terminal inside of your app (including their UI)? Or is your current approach working.

Comment: Im supporting kitty in mac and in linux, calling it with different parameters based on the different platforms. Instead, I would like to call fzf as a "standalone application" in a sense. So the terminal UI is all optional. If I could embed it in a GUI application using a multiplatform toolkit that would be ideal.